# how to extract year from filenames in R

Tags: r, regex

I have list of  files,need to extract year from filenames:

File Names are :

```
[1] "2014_by_country_and_type_Enlarged_Europe.xlsx"            
[2] "20140211_02_2012_vo_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe.xls"       
[3] "20150219_2013_vo_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe.xlsx"
```

Query:

```
 regmatches(files, regexpr("[0-9].*[0-9]", files))
```

But it results:

```
 [1] "2014"            
 [2] "20140211_02_2012" 
 [3]"20150219_2013"
```

I need output as:

```
 2014
 2012
 2013
```

Comment: Will the year always be the last 4 digits that appear before an underscore followed text? Or are there other filenames that don't fit that pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("(\\d{4})(?=_([a-zA-Z]+))",x, perl=T))
```

**Assumption**: selected numbers as year which are followed by an underscore then alphabets.

**Positive lookahead** here works as `digits_of_year(?= underscore_with_alphabets`) matches a digits_of_year that is followed by a underscore_with_alphabets, without making the underscore_with_alphabets part of the match.

**Output**:

```
[1] "2014" "2012" "2013"
```

**data**:

```
x <- c("2014_by_country_and_type_Enlarged_Europe.xlsx", "20140211_02_2012_vo_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe.xls", 
"20150219_2013_vo_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe.xlsx")
```

Comment: didn't got result for this filename:"20090407_2007_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe"

Comment: but got result after modifying file name like this:"20090407_2007_vo_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe"

Comment: @prasanth s k, are you sure? Its working on my system. Copy and paste the regex as it is please. For both i m getting results

Comment: check this one:20090407_2007_By_Country_Enlarged_Europe

Comment: @prasanth s k   You have pasted it wrong, see the solution carefully

Comment: regmatches(file, regexpr("(\\d{4})(?=_([a-z]+))",file, perl=T)),is this correct one??

Comment: Thanks bro for your reply

Comment: @prasanth s k, you are welcome, please accept the solution by checking the green tick mark if the solution has worked

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex with gsub():

```
gsub(".*(\\d{4})_.+", "\\1", str)
[1] "2014" "2012" "2013"
```

It matches any 4 digit number that is followed by a `_`.